file stream objects put() member function
So I'm attempting to implement a Program example from my C++ textbook(Tony Gladdis 9th Edition) involving the get() and put() member functions for file streams and I'm not getting the data to write to the file. This is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream outFile;
    char ch;

    outFile.open("great.txt", ios::out);
    cout << "I can tell if you keep up at this you'll be ";
    cout << "great!" << endl ;

    if(outFile) {
        cin.get(ch); // Problem seems to occur here...
        while(ch != '!') {
            outFile.put(ch);
            cin.get(ch);
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "ERROR: File does not exist.";
    }

    return 0;
}


@pptaszni The program reads symbols from stdin until '!' is read and writes them to outFile, so it's ok.
@daVinci.exe, could you describe in more detail what exactly your "problem" looks like? What did you try?

If there's an error reading from std::cin (including EOF) you will have an infinite loop. Use while (std::cin(get(ch) && ch != '!') { outFile.put(ch); } instead.

@Abstraction you are right, I read the question too fast. In any case, OP could you please substitute std::cin with std::stringstream containing sample input to your program, for reproducibility.

What do you observe when you run the program?

As for your problem, have you tried to debug your program? For example step through the code line by line in a debugger while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens?

After making some assumptions: it seems to work fine

Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing std::fstream outFile; ... outFile.open("great.txt", ios::out); to std::fstream outFile("great.txt", ios::out);. Also, if you use an output stream the code is a bit simpler and clearer: std::ofstream outFile("great.txt");.

Also, nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Also, you don't need to call outFile.close();. The destructor will do that.

Suggestion: handle fail cases early; it tends to make the code easier to read. So instead of if (outFile) ... else ..., use if (!outFile) ... else .... Often the fail case will have an early return, so the code becomes if (!outFile) { /* message */ return EXIT_FAILURE; } and the main-line code won't be indented inside the if or the else.

@PeteBecker thank you for the suggestions! I'm a beginner programmer so all your suggestions are greatly appreciated. Also is I heard that it's bad practice to use namespace std;...Is that true?

@n.m.couldbeanAI when I run the program nothing writes to the file. When I attempted to debug the code it was stuck in the loop. Also while running the value of ch wasn't updating

@daVinci.exe -- take a look at this question and answer, then follow the link in the question that's marked "Possible duplicate:".

That's not exactly your observation, that's your interpretation. An observation looks like this: "when I press keys "X Y Z, I see P Q R appearing on the screen". So my wild guess without knowing any of the details is that there was no ENTER key among those X Y Z you pressed. The next best guess is that you are watching one file, but the program is actually writing to a different file under the same name but ina different directory.
